# can't bridge cast CGImageRef

Tags: objective-c, c, quartz-2d, core-foundation

Why does `(__bridge CGImageRef)(self.theCanvas.imageData)` give me this error?

> Incompatible types casting 'CGImageRef' (aka 'struct CGImage *) to
>   'CGImageRef' with a __bridge cast

Note that self.theCanvas.imageData is a CGImageRef.

Comment: You use `__bridge` when going between Foundation and Objective-C types. But in your case both are `CGImageRef`s, so it shouldn't have a `__bridge`.

Comment: So if CGImageRef isn't Foundation or Objective-C then what is it?

Comment: BTW, I meant to say Core Foundation, not Foundation. And yes, a `CGImageRef` would be a Core Foundation type. What I'm trying to say about your scenario here is that you don't need the `__bridge` in there, because you're not casting between a Core Foundation and Objective-C type.